# Fixed Sidebar on the Right in fluid layout twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sidebar, css-position, fluid-layout

I want to create a fix sidebar on the right of my website but when I give the `style="position:fixed;"` to its div it just comes completely to the left.

```
<div class="span2" style="position:fixed; background-color: white;">  
CONTENT 
</div>
```

How do I do that? Should I give a pixel position to each of the resolutions of the project to keep it responsive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just got how to do it without actually using jquery. It is really simple.

I was just missing to add "right:0" to kick it all the way up to the right. So the following code should do it.

```
<div class="span2" style="position:fixed; right:0">  
CONTENT 
</div>
```

Comment: There is also the .sidebar-nav-fixed class, if you want the Bootstrap way.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter Bootstrap using a grid system that utilizes rows and columns. If you use the .container-fluid and .row-fluid classes you can control where elements are by setting their size relative to their parents size.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/chapmanc/dNRgx/1/

For example...

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span9">
            <div class="hero-unit">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
            <div class="well sidebar-nav">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Would give you a 9 column element followed by a s column element which you can make your sidebar. That puts your sidebar to the right and keeps your layout responsive.

Comment: Thanks Chapman for answering :) But I am afraid is not what I need as if I add style="position:fixed; background-color: white;" to the span3 div everything moves to the left...

Comment: Why do you need the position fixed? With Twitter Bootstrap's grid system the layout is controlled by rows and columns and setting your sidebar fixed in the middle of that would throw it off I think.

Comment: The idea is to put a 160x600 ad placement fixed there that when people scroll down on the page it stays fix so it has better CTRs and conversions. Thanks for your time chapman84 :) I think ill have to tell the div the position where to be in the different layouts depending on resolution. :(

Comment: See if this works for you and let me know. If that's more in line with what you wanted I'll update my answer. http://jsfiddle.net/chapmanc/dNRgx/2/

Comment: Not really as I wanted it fixed when users scroll down.. I tried now with position:fixed float:right and it still comes all the way to the left

Comment: There are jQuery plugins that will handle that. For that effect you have to change the position of the element based on the scroll down of the window. http://anthonygarand.com/sticky/

Comment: Thanks Chapman :D I think you just showed me the path to do it. I will try it tonight (Amsterdam time). Actually we were looking for a similar plugin to do a 9gag style sidebar... a sidebar that gets sticky at a certain point.  I will try to deploy it on our design with my business partner, the developer of our team. :)